# After 20 minutes of inactivity, session should be expired within the application

Tags: php, symfony

After 20 minutes of inactivity, session should be expired within the application.

How can i do this in **symfony2**.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `session` expiration time in `config.yml` file under the `framework` section.

`config.yml`

```
framework:
  secret:        %secret%
  charset:       UTF-8
  error_handler: null
  csrf_protection:
      enabled: true
  router:        { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
  validation:    { enabled: true, annotations: true }
  templating:    { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
  session:
      default_locale: %locale%
      lifetime:       3600
      auto_start:     true
```

change the `session: lifetime` value in seconds defaults to 3600.

Comment: I think gc_maxlifetime is same as lifetime.. right?  But how to logout this session when user inactive.

Comment: Yes.
If the garbage collection handler is invoked, `PHP` will pass the value stored in the `php.ini` directive session `gc_maxlifetime`. Any stored session that was saved more than `gc_maxlifetime` ago should be deleted. This allows one to expire records based on idle time.

Comment: I have added parameter cookie_lifetime: 1200 in config.yml file , But if user active then it should not logout . Logout only when user inactive for 20 minuts. What should I do?

Comment: Setting the cookie lifetime is not appropriate because that can be manipulated by the client, so you have to do the expiry on the server side.The easiest way is to implement this via garbage collection which runs reasonably frequently. The `cookie_lifetime` would be set to a relatively high value, and the garbage collection `gc_maxlifetime` would be set to destroy sessions at whatever the desired idle period is.

Comment: Hi, I have set time of gc_maxlifetime or cookie_lifetime variable in config.yml file but even user active it still logout the application.

Answer (score 1):

Native session storage uses cookies. Another example of handling sessions is by storing them in a database.

Jayson's method will cause the session to expire after one hour. You can also force logout a user at any time like so:

```
$this->container->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken();
```

Note: As of Symfony 2.6, the security.context service has been deprecated and split into two new services: security.authorization_checker and security.token_storage.

[Link to framework configuration for session](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime)

Comment: Means according to Jayson's method only set the lifetime parameter in config file & session automatically logout after that specific time?  Or some another code should write ?

Comment: Right. Jayson's method is "set it and forget it". :) But, you have the option of logging users out manually as well. Although, it's actually `cookie_lifetime: 3600`

Comment: I have added parameter cookie_lifetime: 1200 in config.yml file , But if user active then it should not logout . Logout only when user inactive for 20 minuts. What should I do?